# Cross-Browsing: OpenSans Chrome VS Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

I've a rendering problem with the OpenSans font on Safari. (see the login submit button below)

https://waaave.com/

Proper rendering with Chrome.

[image: Chrome Rendering]

Bad rendering with Safari.

[image: Safari Rendering]

The font appears lighter than it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
* {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about detecting Safari with javascript and than set "OpenSans Bold" instead of OpenSans in the font-family? OpenSans Bold looks better than OpenSans with font-weight to bold.

Comment: is there any way, to do it without using JavaScript?

Comment: Unless there is someone with a solution willing to share it, the only way to find out is to play around with css in both browsers and see if a suitable solution turns up.